# Counting elements that contain colons in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count bus headways --the number of minutes between bus arrivals--in Google Sheets. The arrivals are written as 0:00, 1:00,2:00, etc... I want to count the number of instances of zero-minute buses, one-minute buses, etc..

When I try this =countif(range,"0:00"), I get "0:00" as an answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try with `=countif(range,"=0:00")`?

Comment: I tried both. Neither worked, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the formatting of the range to text and then try

```
=countif(range, "*:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a Pivot Table:

[image: SO48907263example]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a helper column along with `ISNUMBER` and `SEARCH`.

Let's say your data is in A1:A3. In B1, you could put `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(":",A1:A))=TRUE,1,""))`.

That searches for ":" in column A. If the statement evaluates to `TRUE` then a 1 is placed in the corresponding row. If it evaluates to `FALSE` then nothing "" is entered.

Then in C1 you could put `=SUM(B1:B)`.